# What is the minimum electric field strength,that the induced electrical tester led begins to turn-on?

Tags: ac

On the follow photo you may see the standard induced tester,which the led(not neon) inside
turns-on when you hold the metal tip of the screwdriver and move the other side of it close to sockets,
hot AC electric wire,etc,which have a voltage of 220V 50hz.This tester,as far as i know,detects only electric 
field. 
[image]

My
 question is:what is the minimum electric field strength(v/m),that,usually make the led to start turn-on?(the sensitivity)?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that the device you show is a very poor electric field tester.

The AC electric field tester (a quite high sensitivity device) has actually not been around all that long and there are a couple of detailed patents for them. [This one](http://www.google.com/patents/US6828767) shows a generalized schematic so it might help you.

You can see that it's based on a CMOS inverter (something like a [CD4069](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4069ub.pdf)), so the input voltage sensitivity is about 1 V. The sensitivity in V/meter is actually orientation as well as field sensitive. It would be tough to work out without access to the PCB layout, but you could consider it to be roughly defined by the sum of the PCB track length either side of R1. If we guess at say 1" track points ....then at 1 V sensitivity that would be approximately 39 V/m.

[image]

Comment: I dismantle the screwdriver and it hasn't any pcb in it.There are only 10MΩ resistor which touches,at one side,at the inner side of the screw driver tip and at the other side,it touches a close plastic tube,that contains:resistor+transistor+red led and two ag3 battery.Thats all.The led is not turn-on instantly,when you get close to the electric field,the led is turn-on gradually and gets stronger as you get closer.Since,it built different from the one you had described,May you estimate what may be the minimum electric field strength that might make that type of tester to begin turning on?

Comment: @xchcui. The principle does not look very different, though very much less sensitive I'd suggest. The transistor is the amplifier (you need about 650 mV to turn on), and the LED is turned on/off at 50/60 Hz. One way to judge if it's more electric field than capacitive operation would be to hang it from a piece of string (say a meter long), so there are no bulk/body capacitive effects. If it turns on the LED as you bring it closer to a live wire (not supporting an AC load, so no magnetic effects) then it's probably operating as an electric field detector.

Comment: In,general,i have to hold the metal tip of the screwdriver in order that the led will turn-on.I wasn't sure if you meant to hang it to a metal string or non-metal string,so i hold it with a plastic rod of just 10 cm.With that distance the led brightness becomes weaker,so i assume,that at 1m length the led won't turn-on.But maybe you meant to use a metal string?

Comment: @xchui. Non-metal string, and using a plastic rod clearly shows that the major effect is a capacitive divider with your body as the probe (since you have to touch the tip to get it to work)

Comment: Ok.I understand that the led is turns-on due to the small current the flow from me to the ground by the capacitive coupling effect.But can't i use it to estimate magnitude of AC electric fields strength due to the fact that AC capacitors,actually,complete the ac circuit,due to the electric field that created inside them?

Comment: @xchui. Since you have no idea of the capacitive values, there is no way to calculate it's sensitivity.

Comment: Since,this tester is very common in the market,i thought that,from experience,someone will know what is its sensitivity.BTW,the manual says that it can detects microwave oven leaks,so it means that it,also,detects electromagnetic waves.doesn't it?Does it mean,that it can detect 50hz wave and also 2.4Ghz wave?unfortunately,the manual,doesn't say what is the minimum RF power density(w/m2),that will cause the led to turn-on.

Comment: Any thougths,Jack Creasey.

Comment: No, there is insufficient detail.

Comment: Ok.lets leave the power value of the field aside.I understood,from your explanation,that we can detect an hot wire,thanks to capacitive coupling effect.May you explain how does it detect microwave oven leakage?(yes,it,actually,detects microwave leakage beyond certain value,while it has only transistor,resistor,led and batteries)Is it,also,related to capacitive coupling effect?